# Overwrite window.close without popup message

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Here we go again. I have an IE issue. There is an application installed on my server, which uses the function `window.close()`. As soon as you click *Close*, a popup warning message appears and if you click on *Yes* . Make sense, yes, but I would like to overwrite this function in my **custom.js**

I would like to prevent the popup and redirect to another site. This is what I tried:

```
function realClose() {
     alert("test");
     var win=window.open("","_top","","true");
     win.opener=true;
     win.realclosefunc();
     window.location = "/";
}

window.realclosefunc = window.close;
window.close = realClose;
```

Comment: Does this alert close? http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/s9tb3dxy/ - if not, close is read-only in the IE you are looking at. Anyway you are not trying to redirect in your code you are trying to bypass the warning which is there to stop noobs from closing peoples main browser.

Comment: @mplungjan Forgot the row with the redirect. This jsfiddle isn't working in IE, nothing happend. So that means, there is no chance to overwrite or pretend the closing in IE?

Comment: That sounds about right. If you add `alert(window.close)` you still get [native code]

Comment: Damn.. Is there a chance to fire an event before the window.close and then redirect to another page, so the script never reaches to the close function?

Comment: If you can edit the code to not reach the close you should be able to remove or comment out or change the statement that does the close no? Alternatively remove the close on the server using a proxy

Comment: Problem is, that it is a minified js. Nevermind, i will just create a custom button with my own function. Thanks for your help!